# Nodejs, mongoose and problems with queries in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose this scenario.
I have a collection where I store products, this products have a property called "props" and this is an array of objects, that have properties like measure, weight.

The problem comes when I'm trying to insert new products. I'm receiving an array of objects that will be inserted, but each element of the array **could** have a property called "propsReference", and If it's there, it would be an ID that refers to the object that's currently inserted and have some props

So, if it has the propsReference property with an ID, I want to copy the properties of this object to the object I'm going to insert

The only solution I can think of is doing a foreach to the first array, if it has the propsReference do a query, get the props and insert it into this element of the array as a new property of the object.

But I'm having a lot of problems with doing queries inside a for loop, there's any way in mongoose or something to avoid that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show use some code examples

Comment: maybe you should look at mongoose populate mechanics: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html